# How do I convert SmartyStreets' jQuery.LiveAddress plugin to its JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, smartystreets

I have a website where the jQuery.LiveAddress plugin is implemented, but it was deprecated and then totally removed by SmartyStreets in 2014.

https://www.smartystreets.com/archive/jquery-plugin/website/configure

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/5.2/jquery.liveaddress.min.js"></script>
<script>var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
    key: "YOUR_WEBSITE_KEY_HERE",
    debug: true,
    target: "US|INTERNATIONAL",
    addresses: [{
        address1: '#street-address',
        locality: '#city',
        administrative_area: '#state',
        postal_code: '#zip',
        country: '#country'
    }]
});
</script>
```

There is now a JavaScript SDK: https://www.smartystreets.com/docs/sdk/javascript

```
const SmartyStreetsSDK = require("smartystreets-javascript-sdk");
const SmartyStreetsCore = SmartyStreetsSDK.core;
const Lookup = SmartyStreetsSDK.usStreet.Lookup;

// for Server-to-server requests, use this code:
// let authId = process.env.SMARTY_AUTH_ID;
// let authToken = process.env.SMARTY_AUTH_TOKEN;
// const credentials = new SmartyStreetsCore.StaticCredentials(authId, authToken);

// for client-side requests (browser/mobile), use this code:
let key = process.env.SMARTY_WEBSITE_KEY;
const credentials = new SmartyStreetsCore.SharedCredentials(key);
```

It says "for client-side requests (browser/mobile), use this code", but am I correct in assuming that it is not possible to get this code working as browser JavaScript? Wouldn't I need to be running node as a service on my server to be using this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key file that I was missing was the [browserify.js](https://github.com/smarty/smartystreets-javascript-sdk/blob/master/browserify.js) file in the SmartyStreets JavaScript SDK.

1. Run `npm install smartystreets-javascript-sdk --save-dev` in your project's root directory
2. Change directory to `node_modules/smartystreets-javascript-sdk`
3. Run `npm install` in this directory
4. Run `rm -rf dist` && `node browserify.js` (script will fail if the dist folder exists)
5. Copy dist/smartystreets-sdk-1.*.*.min.js to a dependencies folder for your main project.

I tried to write a grunt task to take the SmartyStreets SDK and automatically update it, browserify it, and deploy it along with the rest of our website, but it turned out to be too much of a hassle with the time constraints given. If anyone else writes a grunt task for this please share!

Answer (score 2):

The client-side code example can be used in the browser, not just in node. You will need to store your website key in a different way since the browser doesn't have access to `process.env`. You can store the website key in plaintext here since it will be tied to your hostname.

You will need to be using some kind of library or JS bundler to process the require statement you see on line 1. You can also import the SDK if that's what works better for your setup, for example

`import SmartyStreetsSDK from "smartystreets-javascript-sdk"`

Something to keep in mind with using the SDK vs the jQuery plugin is that the SDK does not provide and UI elements on the page. It's less of a drop in solution than the jQuery plugin is. You will need to design and create your own UI elements for the user to interact with.

disclaimer: I work for Smarty (formerly SmartyStreets)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and unfortunately smarty streets decided to make it more difficult for users to implement their product.

Upon my search I came across this fiddle, it doesn't have all of the features the jquery plugin did but it is a good place to start that doesn't require building your own suggestion UI.

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/uptgh7c8/embed/"></script>
```

[jsfiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/smartystreets/uptgh7c8/)